# Using python's mock patch.object to change the return value of a method called within another method

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, patch

Is it possible to mock a return value of a function called within another function I am trying to test? I would like the mocked method (which will be called in many methods I'm testing) to returned my specified variables each time it is called. For example:

```
class Foo:
    def method_1():
       results = uses_some_other_method()
    def method_n():
       results = uses_some_other_method()
```

In the unit test, I would like to use mock to change the return value of `uses_some_other_method()` so that any time it is called in `Foo`, it will return what I defined in `@patch.object(...)`

Comment: For reference, anyone can refer to this well-narrated article https://realpython.com/python-mock-library/

Answer (score 228, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this; with patch and with patch.object

Patch assumes that you are not directly importing the object but that it is being used by the object you are testing as in the following

```
#foo.py
def some_fn():
    return 'some_fn'

class Foo(object):
    def method_1(self):
        return some_fn()
```

```
#bar.py
import foo
class Bar(object):
    def method_2(self):
        tmp = foo.Foo()
        return tmp.method_1()
```

```
#test_case_1.py
import bar
from mock import patch

@patch('foo.some_fn')
def test_bar(mock_some_fn):
    mock_some_fn.return_value = 'test-val-1'
    tmp = bar.Bar()
    assert tmp.method_2() == 'test-val-1'
    mock_some_fn.return_value = 'test-val-2'
    assert tmp.method_2() == 'test-val-2'
```

If you are directly importing the module to be tested, you can use patch.object as follows:

```
#test_case_2.py
import foo
from mock import patch

@patch.object(foo, 'some_fn')
def test_foo(test_some_fn):
    test_some_fn.return_value = 'test-val-1'
    tmp = foo.Foo()
    assert tmp.method_1() == 'test-val-1'
    test_some_fn.return_value = 'test-val-2'
    assert tmp.method_1() == 'test-val-2'
```

In both cases some_fn will be 'un-mocked' after the test function is complete.

Edit:
In order to mock multiple functions, just add more decorators to the function and add arguments to take in the extra parameters

```
@patch.object(foo, 'some_fn')
@patch.object(foo, 'other_fn')
def test_foo(test_other_fn, test_some_fn):
    ...
```

Note that the closer the decorator is to the function definition, the earlier it is in the parameter list.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of the difference between patch and patch.object.

Comment: how to `patch.object` two functions within the same class?

Comment: What if foo is a library I have no access to and what I want to mock is the call to method_1?

Comment: @skytreader the fact that you don't have access to the library doesn't matter, you could still use either method (patch.object would be easiest). In that case you'd add a method_1 property to the returned [mock object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#the-mock-class) and assign a return value to that such as test_some_obj.method_1.return_value = 'some_value'

Comment: Thank you so much for this phrase: "the closer the decorator is to the function definition, the earlier it is in the parameter list." Just spent 1 hour debugging this...

Comment: @LanaNova same here. I expected the order of parameters to be similar to how the patch.object listed them.

Comment: sorry for the dumb question, but what is the `test_some_fun` being used for?meaning does one need to define `test_some_fun` inside the test class?

Comment: @ApJo `test_some_fn` is the name given to the mock passed through to the test function via `@patch.object(foo, 'some_fn')`. `some_fn` is the function in the package `foo`. I suppose a better name would be `mock_some_fn` as it represents the mock object.

Answer (score 52):

This can be done with something like this:

```
# foo.py
class Foo:
    def method_1():
        results = uses_some_other_method()


# testing.py
from mock import patch

@patch('Foo.uses_some_other_method', return_value="specific_value"):
def test_some_other_method(mock_some_other_method):
    foo = Foo()
    the_value = foo.method_1()
    assert the_value == "specific_value"
```

Here's a source that you can read: [Patching in the wrong place](http://alexmarandon.com/articles/python_mock_gotchas/)

Comment: Many thanks. The article you referred is really helpful.

Answer (score 13):

Let me clarify what you're talking about: you want to test `Foo` in a testcase, which calls external method `uses_some_other_method`. Instead of calling the actual method, you want to mock the return value.

```
class Foo:
    def method_1():
       results = uses_some_other_method()
    def method_n():
       results = uses_some_other_method()
```

Suppose the above code is in `foo.py` and `uses_some_other_method` is defined in module `bar.py`. Here is the unittest:

```
import unittest
import mock

from foo import Foo


class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):

    def setup(self):
        self.foo = Foo()

    @mock.patch('foo.uses_some_other_method')
    def test_method_1(self, mock_method):
        mock_method.return_value = 3
        self.foo.method_1(*args, **kwargs)

        mock_method.assert_called_with(*args, **kwargs)
```

If you want to change the return value every time you passed in different arguments, `mock` provides [`side_effect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#quick-guide).

Comment: def setup(self): with a capital "U" def setUp(self):
I wasted so much time on this!

Answer (score 4):

To add to Silfheed's answer, which was useful, I needed to patch multiple methods of the object in question. I found it more elegant to do it this way:

Given the following function to test, located in `module.a_function.to_test.py`:

```
from some_other.module import SomeOtherClass

def add_results():
    my_object = SomeOtherClass('some_contextual_parameters')
    result_a = my_object.method_a()
    result_b = my_object.method_b()
    
    return result_a + result_b
```

To test this function (or class method, it doesn't matter), one can patch multiple methods of the class `SomeOtherClass` by using `patch.object()` in combination with `sys.modules`:

```
@patch.object(sys.modules['module.a_function.to_test'], 'SomeOtherClass')
def test__should_add_results(self, mocked_other_class):
  mocked_other_class().method_a.return_value = 4
  mocked_other_class().method_b.return_value = 7

  self.assertEqual(add_results(), 11)
```

This works no matter the number of methods of `SomeOtherClass` you need to patch, with independent results.

Also, using the same patching method, an actual instance of `SomeOtherClass` can be returned if need be:

```
@patch.object(sys.modules['module.a_function.to_test'], 'SomeOtherClass')
def test__should_add_results(self, mocked_other_class):
  other_class_instance = SomeOtherClass('some_controlled_parameters')
  mocked_other_class.return_value = other_class_instance 
  ...
```