# Using python's mock patch for changing the return value of a method called in a method used within another method

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, patch

Is it possible to mock a return value of a function which is called within a function which again is used in another method? I know it is a very complicated structure. I would like the mocked method to return a specific value. The following example shows the structure:

```
#foo.py
from bar import other_method

class Foo:
    def method_1():
       results = other_method()
```

```
#bar.py

def method_to_be_patched():
    return 'abc'

def other_method():
    res = method_to_be_patched()
    ...
    return 'result'
```

I would like to test `method_1` and patch the `method_to_be_patched`. I read a related issue ([Using python's mock patch.object to change the return value of a method called within another method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191275/using-pythons-mock-patch-object-to-change-the-return-value-of-a-method-called-w)) and tried the following

```
#test.py
from unittest import TestCase 
from unittest.mock import patch 
from foo import Foo

patch_value = '123'


class Test(TestCase):
   def setUp(self):
       self.foo = Foo()

   @patch('Foo.other_method.method_to_be_patched', return_value = patch_value)
   def test_method_1(mocked_method):
       self.foo.method_1()
```

I would expect that the patch would return the patched value at the point where `method_to_be_patched` is called within `self.foo.method_1()`. But the interpreter displays the error message "function other_method at ... does not have the attribute 'method_to_be_patched'"

Comment: `method_to_be_patched` is a name in the `bar` module imported by `foo.py`, update your source code with the required imports

Comment: The argument for `patch` should be a string, and as has been mentioned, `method_to_be_patched` is in `bar`. As you don't import it directly, you can just do `@patch("bar.method_to_be_patched", return_value=...)`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I added the imports and the str in the first patch argument. I tried the suggestion ```@patch("bar.method_to_be_patched", return_value=...)```. But this does not work. It does not recognize the patch in this case.